# What are some methods for parcooking hamburgers?

Tags: hamburgers, parcooking

Im trying to find a faster way to serve cheeseburgers. I was thinking maybe i could par cook 10-15 patties up to 90% done right before rush hour then store them in a steam table with beef broth, then place them back on the grill per order to finish cooking them. Does anybody have any better suggestions?

Comment: There's an older question about parcooking and freezing (not recommended), but one of the answers (other than the 'don't do it' ones), advocated for what you're suggesting : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/91723/67

Comment: also related (although dealing with fully cooked leftovers): https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75453/67

Comment: Yea, I'm not particular fond off the cooking and freezing method. Thanks I'll check those out! :)

Comment: How thick are your patties? Burgers shouldn't take more than a couple minutes each side.

Comment: They are 3/4 inche on the edges and about a 1/2 inch in the center.

Comment: I need them done in about 5 mins compared to 10-12, most of my customers come on their 30 min lunch break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For speed and quality this is the perfect application for sous vide cooking.  You can cook burgers to varying degrees of doneness.  They can hang out in the water bath, at a degree or two below the rarest burger, for up to 2 hours.  Just quickly sear or grill to finish.